# Can't Get Specific Channel - Discord.js v11.6.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am getting this error when I run:  (node:7112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined

```
        const Discord = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (client, message, member, args) => {

    let Help = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`[client] Help - ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
    .addField(`.help                  `, `bring up help list.`)
    .setColor("#ff1100");
    message.channel.send(Help);

    /* Command Logger */
        var DateTime = new Date();
        var Hours = DateTime.getHours();
        Hours = (Hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + Hours;
        var Minutes = DateTime.getMinutes();
        Minutes = (Minutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + Minutes;
        var Seconds = DateTime.getSeconds();
        Seconds = (Seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + Seconds;

        let CommandLog = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .addField(`Command: Help`)

        member.guild.cache.channels.cache.get('820470375602847745').send(CommandLog);
    /* Command Logger */
    message.delete();
};

exports.help = {
    name: 'help',
};
```

Comment: i added it for you

Comment: I did add it, its on line #2

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's irrelevant since It works without the Command Logger.

Comment: I only need help sending a message to a specific channel using an id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `member.guild` is `undefined` which probably means `member` is not a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object. Check if you're passing `message.member` as the third argument when calling the `run` function (inside the `message` event handler). After fixing it, remove the `cache` call on `member.guild`. The [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild) object does not have a `cache` property. And since you're using discord.js v11, `guild.channels` returns a [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Collection). So, you can use `guild.channels.get` to get the channel. The return type of `guild.channels` was changed to [`GuildChannelManager`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/GuildChannelManager) in v12.

```js
// discord.js v11
member.guild.channels.get('820470375602847745')

// v12
member.guild.channels.cache.get('820470375602847745')
```

You could also use `message.guild.channels` in v11 to get access to the channels collection.

```js
// discord.js v11
message.guild.channels.get('820470375602847745')

// v12
message.guild.channels.cache.get('820470375602847745')
```

Comment: I tried
```
        let channel = message.guild.channels.cache.get('820470375602847745')
        if(channel) channel.send(CommandLog);
```
but the output was: (node:11660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: Which version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: its in the title: v11.6.4

Comment: @bananapie Ah, `guild.channels` returns a `GuildChannelManager` only from 
discord.js v12. I've updated my answer with the code required for v11.

Comment: Ok, yeah that worked (message.guild.channels.get('820470375602847745')) Thanks Alot.